# Ruby method returns hash values in binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I wrote a method that takes six names then generates an array of seven random numbers using four 6-sided dice. The lowest value of the four 6-sided dice is dropped, then the remainder is summed to create the value. The value is then added to an array.

Once seven numbers have been generated, the array is then ordered from highest to lowest and the lowest value is dropped. Then the array of names and the array of values are zipped together to create a hash.

This method ensures that the first name in the array of names receives the highest value, and the last name receives the lowest.

This is the result of calling the method:

```
{:strength=>1, :dexterity=>1, :constitution=>0, :intelligence=>0, :wisdom=>0, :charisma=>1}
```

As you can see, all the values I receive are either "1" or "0". I have no idea how this is happening.

Here is the code:

```
module PriorityStatGenerator

  def self.roll_stats(first_stat, second_stat, third_stat, fourth_stat, fifth_stat, sixth_stat)
    stats_priority = [first_stat, second_stat, third_stat, fourth_stat, fifth_stat, sixth_stat].map(&:to_sym)
    roll_array = self.roll

    return Hash[stats_priority.zip(roll_array)]
  end

  private

  def self.roll

    roll_array = []

    7.times {
      roll_array << Array.new(4).map{ 1 + rand(6) }.sort.drop(1).sum
    }
    roll_array.reverse.delete_at(6)
  end
end
```

This is how I'm calling the method while I'm testing:

```
render plain: PriorityStatGenerator.roll_stats(params[:prioritize][:first_stat], params[:prioritize][:second_stat], params[:prioritize][:third_stat], params[:prioritize][:fourth_stat], params[:prioritize][:fifth_stat], params[:prioritize][:sixth_stat])
```

I added `require 'priority_stat_generator'` where I'm calling the method, so it is properly calling it.

Can someone help me make it return proper values between 1 and 18?

Comment: That code should not work. `delete_at` returns the deleted element, which is a `Fixnum`, then `zip` should fail for not getting an `Enumerable`. I can't see how you're getting a binary mapping.

Comment: Is there something I can replace the `delete_at` with?

Comment: `delete_at` is not wrong, it just doesnt return the array. So return the array after that line (insert `roll_array` below it). Alternately, you can use `take(6)` - this will return first 6 elements. But since I cant see how your program is doing what you claim it is doing, I cant be sure this will fix it. (Incidentally, `Array.new(4).map` can be replaced more efficiently with `4.times.map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a refactoring to simplify things and use an actually random number generator, as `rand` is [notoriously terrible](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25):

```
require 'securerandom'

module PriorityStatGenerator
  def self.roll_stats(*stats)
    Hash[
      stats.map(&:to_sym).zip(self.roll(stats.length).reverse)
    ]
  end

private
  def self.roll(n = 7)
    (n + 1).times.map do
      4.times.map { 1 + SecureRandom.random_number(6) }.sort.drop(1).inject(:+)
    end.sort.last(n)
  end
end
```

This makes use of `inject(:+)` so it works in plain Ruby, no ActiveSupport required.

The use of `*stats` makes the `roll_stats` function way more flexible. Your version has a very rigid number of parameters, which is confusing and often obnoxious to use. Treating the arguments as an array avoids a lot of the binding on the expectation that there's six of them.

As a note it's not clear why you're making N+1 roles and then discarding the last. That's the same as generating N and discarding none. Maybe you meant to sort them and take the N best?

**Update:** Added `sort` and `reverse` to properly map in terms of priority.

Comment: Looks good. Sorting is an expensive way to find the smallest value, so something like the following would be more efficient: `a = 4.times.map { SecureRandom.random_number(6) }; 3 + a.inject(:+) - a.min`.

Comment: I was trying to keep the top 6 rolls, and discarding the last. Sort of like a mulligan.

Comment: In that case you want `.sort.last(n)` for the best N rolls. What you're doing is arbitrarily discarding from an unsorted list.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Probably true, but for infrequently executed functions operating on small lists the difference is immeasurable.

Comment: Since Ruby v2.0, [Enumerable.max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) takes an optional parameter `n` to return the `n` largest values of the collection, so you can use `.max(n)` in place of `.sort.last(n)`. Similar for `min`, `max_by` and `min_by`. Ninja: yes on "outside" ordering but ordering is not needed to calculate sums.

Comment: I'm trying to also keep the order in which the names are ordered, so that the first name gets the highest value, the second name gets the second highest, third name gets the third highest, etc.

Comment: Just saying that if you want them sorted, you'll have to `sort` them. Otherwise you're just generating and discarding a value for no reason.

Comment: It seems like the stat order gets mixed up because when I run `PriorityStatGenerator.roll_stats(strength, dexterity, constitution, intelligence, wisdom, charisma)` I get the following output: `=>{:strength=>18, :dexterity=>11, :constitution=>9, :intelligence=>16, :wisdom=>14, :charisma=>17}` which means that the order gets switched around at some point.

Comment: If you're using Ruby 1.9 or better the Hash will preserve insertion order. Before that there's no expectation of order preservation.  I've updated the code with a `sort` call and it works for me. If you're using Ruby 1.8 it'll get scrambled every time.

Comment: Looks like I had to restart the rails console in order for the changes to take effect. It works with the rails console now; however, I still get binary when trying to call it in my model. I'll have to look into that myself I suppose. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Final note: Restating the rails server solved the issue of the method returning binary digits. I have no idea what caused the bug, or how restarting the server worked, but it did. Weird.

Comment: Any code outside of `app/` or `config/routes.rb` will require a restart to take effect. If you put this in `lib/` or `config/initializers` you'd need to restart. When writing a library like this, be sure to make an associated unit test to verify the functionality before trying to debug how it integrates with the rest of your application.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn to use IRB or PRY to test snippets of your code, or better, learn to use a debugger. They give you insight into what your code is doing.

In IRB:

```
[7,6,5,4,3,2,1].delete_at(6)
1
```

In other words, `delete_at(6)` is doing what it's supposed to, but that's not what you want. Instead, perhaps slicing the array will behave more like you expect:

```
>> [7,6,5,4,3,2,1][0..-2]
[
    [0] 7,
    [1] 6,
    [2] 5,
    [3] 4,
    [4] 3,
    [5] 2
]
```

Also, in your code, it's not necessary to `return` a value when that operation is the last logical step in a method. Ruby will return the last value seen:

```
Hash[stats_priority.zip(roll_array)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As amadan said, I can't see how you are getting the results you are, but their is a definite bug in your code.

The last line in self.roll is the return value.

```
roll_array.reverse.delete_at(6)
```

Which is going to return the value that was deleted. You need to add a new lines to return the roll_array instead of the delete_at value. You are also not sorting your array prior to removing that last item which will give you the wrong values as well.

```
def self.roll
  roll_array = []
  7.times {
    roll_array << Array.new(4).map{ 1 + rand(6) }.sort.drop(1).sum
  }
  roll_array.sort.drop(1) 
  roll_array
end
```